# How do I display an error correctly and proceed if a user types in their email correctly?

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I am trying to get an error to display correctly and it is not working even though I type in an email correctly. What the program is supposed to do is when a user clicks the login button, bring them to a page. If the user types in an incorrect email address, display an error.

[image]

[image]

The program is supposed to check if their email address is in the database as well. I think I got the SQL wrong on that part, can you guys check it?

Here is my index.php where the errors reside in the file on lines 27-40.

```
    <?php

// Get your db connection file, be sure it has a new connection to the
// tech support database
require('../model/database.php');

// Get the models needed - work will need to be done in both
require('../model/customer_db.php');
require('../model/product_db.php');
require('../model/registration_db.php');

$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
if ($action == NULL) {
    $action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
    if ($action == null) {
        $action = 'product_register';
    }
}

//When the user clicks the first link on the home page, bring them to the login page.
if ($action == 'product_register') {
    include('customer_login.php');
}

//When the user clicks the login button, the system checks for errors in their typing.
//If no errors are present, proceed to product_register.php.
else if($action == 'login'){
    $productCode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $email= filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if ($productCode == NULL || $productCode == FALSE || $email == NULL || $email == FALSE ) {
    $error = 'Invalid email. Try again.';
    include('../errors/error.php');
    }else{   
        $custEmail = get_email($email);
        if($custEmail){
            $products = get_products();
            $productName = get_products_by_name($productCode);
            header("Location: 'product_register.php'");
        }else{
        $error = 'Invalid email. Try again.';
        include('../errors/error.php');
        }
    }
}

//When the user clicks register product, the system registers the product in their name.
else if ($action == 'register_product') {
    $customer_id = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'customer_id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);
    $product_code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'product_code');
    if ($customer_id == NULL || $customer_id == FALSE || $product_code == NULL || $product_code == FALSE) {
        $error = "Select a product and try again.";
        include('../errors/error.php');
    } else {
        add_registration($customer_id, $product_code);
        header("Location: .?customer_id=$customer_id");
    }
}
```

Here is the mySQL code that is found in customer_db.php:

```
<?php
//Get a customer by their email address
function get_email($email) {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID = :customer_id';    
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':customer_id', $email);
    $statement->execute(); 

    $status = false;
    if($statement->rowCount()){
        $status = true;
    }    
    return $status;
}
```

here are the columns for the customers table:
[image]

Customer_login.php

```
<?php include '../view/header.php';?>
<main>

    <h2>Customer Login</h2>
    <p>You must login before you can register a product.</p>

    <form id="login_form" action="index.php" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="action" value="login" />

        <label>Email:</label>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
        <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
    </form>
</main>
<?php include '../view/footer.php'; ?>
```

Did I code the SQL correctly? and did I code the errors the way they are supposed to be coded?

EDIT: Added the customer_login.php file for clarification.

EDIT 2: I added Rajdeep Paul's code in. Still not letting me into the application. I did everything he asked.

Comment: Where are you using `get_email()` function in your code?

Comment: @RajdeepPaul I am not using the function. when I type it in `($action == 'login')` in index.php, I get an undefined variable $email.

Comment: So how are you validating customer's email id i.e. whether a customer's email id exists in the db table or not? I don't see any code related to that, your code will carry on with `$products = get_products(); ...` even if a user types in a bogus email id.

Comment: @RajdeepPaul, I am validating it with `$customer = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);`

Comment: Change `WHERE customerID = :customer_id` to `WHERE email = :customer_id` in `customer_db.php` if you want to fetch the customer by their email..

Comment: @MichaelK I changed the SQL to what you said. I believe it worked, now I am getting an `Undefined variable: customer_id` error whenever I login.

Comment: @HawkBlade124 I've given an answer below. Hopefully this will resolve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code, such as:

- Since you're using `POST` method in your form, there's no point using `INPUT_GET` type in `filter_input()` function. It should always be `INPUT_POST`. So you need to change your `$action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action'); if ($action == NULL) { ... }` code snippet in the following way,

  ```
  $action = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'action');
  if ($action == null) {
      $action = 'product_register';
  }
  ```
- You'll always get *Undefined variable* error in `$custEmail = get_email($email);` statement, unless you explicitly define a variable named `$email`. Besides, this statement should be like this,

  ```
  $custEmail = get_email($_POST['email']);
  ```
- You'll always get `$customer` as `null` in `$customer = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);` statement. As discussed in point #1, use `INPUT_POST` instead of `INPUT_GET`.

  ```
  $customer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
  ```
- You're not *properly* checking whether the customer's email id exists in the db table or not. Since `get_email()` function doesn't return anything, you won't get any value in `$custEmail` in point #2.

So based on the last three points, change your `get_email()` function and `else if($action == 'login'){ ... }` block in the following way,

```
function get_email($email) {
    global $db;
    $query = 'SELECT * FROM customers WHERE email = :email';    
    $statement = $db->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindValue(':email', $email);
    $statement->execute(); 

    $status = false;
    if($statement->rowCount()){
        $status = true;
    }    
    return $status;
}
```

and

```
if($action == 'product_register'){    
    // your code
}else if($action == 'login'){
    $productCode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');
    $customer = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
    if ($productCode == NULL || $productCode == FALSE || $email == NULL || $email == FALSE ) {
        // error code
    }else{   
        $custEmail = get_email($customer);
        if($custEmail){
            $products = get_products();
            $productName = get_products_by_name($productCode);
            // your code
        }else{
            // error code
        }
    }
}else if($action == 'register_product'){
    // your code  
}
```

Comment: And just to give you one more point, there's no `name` input field in your form. So `$productCode` will always be null. I'm guessing you only showed a part of your form. If not, create a name input field in your form like this: `<input type="text" name="name" />`

Comment: I have entered in all the code and it is still not letting me into the application even if I put in the correct email address. the email id is associated with the emails column in the image provided. The replaced code is in my main post. Thank you very much by the way for your help.

Comment: @HawkBlade124 I've updated the `get_email()` function in my answer. Please test your application with the updated code snippet.

Comment: @HawkBlade124 Plus, why did you remove `email` input field from your form? Don't delete/replace the `email` input field, just create one more `name` input field of *text* type, as mentioned in [my comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42461643/how-do-i-display-an-error-correctly-and-proceed-if-a-user-types-in-their-email-c/42462788#comment72067873_42462788).

Comment: All right, that works! But, I just need to have one field.

Comment: @HawkBlade124 Well, if you don't have any `name` input field from your form, you won't get anything with this statement `$productName = get_products_by_name($productCode);` because `$productCode` would be `null`.

Comment: So what you are saying is that I need to have both of those fields in the customer login page in order for this to work?

Comment: @HawkBlade124 Yes. Or, just remove these two statements from your `else if($action == 'login'){ ... }` block, `$productCode = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name');` and `$productName = get_products_by_name($productCode);`. This way, you don't have to add any `name` input field in your form for login, only email would be enough.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate this help! You are awesome!

Comment: @HawkBlade124 You're very welcome! Glad I could help. :-)